# Formatting issue while patching drop down values in ngx summernote

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am patching a drop down value on the content editor here. So when I normally patch it works. But at a particular condition,

**Say for example**

When I hit enter move to next line type a word and then try to patch the dropdown value the word patches in the next line. I want it to patch it in the same line. Its a weird scenario

I have searched for answers in stack overflow but couldn't get an answer. Please help if you guys know. If you feel like I haven't explained the question well please comment below.

I have attached a Stackblitz link below

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-e6sxnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The question is unclear, your stakblitz seems to contain a lot of extra code that's unrelated and there is no input box to do any typing as you say in your question.

Comment: Yeah there is some extra code. Excuse me for that. Just type a word hit enter and come to the next line. Keeping the cursor there select a dropdown value. Now the dropdown value gets added in next line instead of the same line. Thats my issue @JerMah

Comment: Ah the editor didn't load for me before, hence the confusion.

Comment: can you see it now

Comment: now the editor loads

Answer (score 0):

It's because you add the word outside of the `<p> </p>` tags. I've added some code that removes the `</p>` tag, adds the word and then closes the paragraph again using regex. This is not ideal because it can still fail if the last thing in the string wasn't a paragraph.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-maiuua?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
  changeValue(ev) {
    const regex = /(<\/p>)$/gm;
    if (regex.test(this.textValue)) {
      this.textValue = this.textValue.replace(regex, "");
      this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}</p>`;
    } else {
      this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}`;
    }
    console.log("textValue", this.textValue);
  }
```

Comment: So your saying that this isnt a permanent solution to this? Is there any alternate permanent solutionpls?

Comment: It's diffucult to know what you are trying to do in the bigger picture so I don't know.

Comment: As you said I am getting issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667718/find-and-replace-typescript-angular