# find and replace typescript angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, summernote

I use a dropdown which when a value gets selected sits as a word on the content editor.I am trying to find and replace words from the content editor. I was able to replace but at some scenarios it doesn't work.

I am trying to replace city to the name Newyork
For example from the drop down values if I choose city in my console log the content editor content shows it as Newyork

So at first it works but if I choose other dropdown values and once again when I choose city it doesn't work

For example try to choose City first Name second and City again you will see that the second time when you chose city the console log value for city didnt change as Newyork

Please help if u guys know

changeValue() is the function name

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-ej4xpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: In the sample if selected city, City only showing in the editer it is not Newyork :(

Comment: Hi sir. check in the console log please. I am talking about the change in the consolelog.

Comment: Please check my answer let me know if it is not working

Answer (score -1):

I did something(but not sure why are using regex her) now it is working as expected for your quetsion.

```
changeValue(ev) {
    const regex = /(<\/p>)$/gm;
    if (regex.test(this.textValue)) {
      this.textValue = this.textValue.replace(regex, "");
      this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}</p>`;
    } else {
      this.textValue += ` ${ev.value}`;
    }
    let cleanText = this.textValue.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    let abc = cleanText.replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");

    let final = abc.replace("City", "Newyork");
    this.textValue = final;
    console.log("textValue", final);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-tauve8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Its not working. Only the first occurence of city is changing to newyork. Try copy pasting a value

Comment: copy paste this "I am inviting you to  City. Sm mr  Name please come to  City" and select a dropdownvalue you will see that only the first occurence of city changes to newyork

Comment: Then I am not clear about the requirement. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I am trying to do mailmerge option here. So I am trying to replace placeholder values such as City to Newyork in the editor and check in console log. If I copy paste this "I am inviting you to City. Sm mr Name please come to City" and select a dropdownvalue you will see that only the first occurence of city changes to newyork and rest of it dont

Comment: I want the city change only in console not in editor because only when passsing the editor content I change it